# How to use a variable as index to subset a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I am trying to figure out how to use a variable as index to subset a dataframe. If I use numeric values I do not have any problem to select the columns I'm interested in from the dataframe:

```
m1 <- c(0.3,0.2,0.1,0.1,0.3,0)
m2 <- c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.2)
m3 <- c(0.2,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.2,0)

input <- data.frame(m1,m2,m3)

# I select the first two columns
example <- input[,1:2]
```

and the output is what I expect:

```
   m1  m2
1 0.3 0.1
2 0.2 0.1
3 0.1 0.1
4 0.1 0.2
5 0.3 0.3
6 0.0 0.2
```

However, if I define the variable `m <- 1L` or like `m<-1` and I try to extract the columns:

```
example2 <- input[,m:m+1]
```

The output is:

```
[1] 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.2
```

Why? And how to use a variable as index to select columns from a dataframe?

Comment: try `input[,m:(m+1)]`

Comment: Wow! It works. Thanks. Such a stupid thing! Out of curiosity, do you know why is like that? Just an anecdote, using `select(input,m:m+1)` provided the same unexpected result.

Comment: parentheses notation returns the result of evaluating the expression inside the parentheses

Comment: Yeah, but m+1 is the same as (m+1), right?

Comment: Yes.. but the problem occurs when the `1:m`-part of 1:m+1 get evaluated first, and the 1 is added afterward. Compare  the output of `1:2+1` with `1:(2+1)` to see the difference on your console.

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap m+1 in parenthesis so its get calculated before the `1:`part is evaluated.

here's why:

```
> 1:2+1
[1] 2 3  #the numeric vactor 1:2, with the value of 1 added to it
> 1:(2+1) 
[1] 1 2 3 #the numeric vector 1:3
```

Comment: Great explanation! Thank you.